# Manjaro boot errors

Tags: manjaro, home

When running linux I get an error about starting `/home` partition.
This section is encrypted.

Below is the log journalctl-xe from the start.

Since the log file is too large, I leave a link to it.

And Yes. I have no idea what's really important, so post it in its entirety.

[Log file](https://wdho.ru/Ohz)